# How to display DNS cache without using ipconfig?

Tags: dns, ipconfig

I am having a problem trying to get the DNS cache without using `ipconfig`.

I am unable to use the `ipconfig` tool and was looking for an alternative command line tool to display the DNS cache, just like in this command:

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

Comment: Tried get-dnsclientcache in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the netsh command if you're using a newer version of Windows.

[Check out this technet article for more information](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)

From the article:

> Syntax
>   show dns [[name=]InterfaceName]
>
> Parameters
>   [ name= ] InterfaceName   : Specifies the name of the interface whose DNS configuration you want to display. The InterfaceName parameter must match the name of the interface as specified in Network Connections. If InterfaceName contains spaces, use quotation marks around the text (for example, "Interface Name").

Comment: This doesn't show the DNS cache, it only shows the current DNS resolvers. Here's an example of how to use it anyways since you didn't give any example: `netsh interface show interface` will show the name of all interfaces, once you have the name of your interface you can use this command: `netsh interface ip show dns "Wi-Fi"` if you don't state the name of the interface, it will show the DNS resolvers for all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a lame answer, but sending the output to a file means you can see all the output:

`ipconfig /displaydns > dns-cache.txt`

Comment: I realise that isn't helpful if you are restricted from running ipconfig, but I was looking for a graphic interface for this, but then realised I just needed a better interface for reading the text.

Comment: This method generated a useful to read TXT file.